# Adding a date of Using Selenium issue

Tags: selenium, junit

I am actually wanting to avoid using the YUI date picker to enter the date and simply send keys 050576 or 05/05/76.

```
    getDriver().findElement(By.xpath(birthDatePath)).sendKeys(efdob);
```

Using Chrome I can "Paste as plain text" using the slashes, but with simply "Paste", I run into issues as the field wants to force and mask the entry individually by MM DD YY.  Selenium does well when it can simply enter data, but is there a way to use the Chrome feature that seems to work for entering this correctly or a better way to use the widget?? Below is an image showing the widget.

[image]

Thank you,

Comment: For this particular instance, the actual date was not important so I elected to "click through" some of the widget.  I would however like to be able to add a date that uses this widget without using the widget.

Answer (score 1):

In such cases I prefer updating value directly using Javascript instead of using `sendKeys`

```
driver.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', arguments[1])", inputField, value);
```

Comment: I would use this method only as a last extreme. I've tested a large amounts of code with Selenium. Code that integrate widgets from a variety of sources. Sometimes the widget is flat out buggy. Or integration of library A with widget X causes issues. This method bypasses the key event machinery, which means that any issue with how the key event handlers are setup won't be caught.